# Integrating PHP into a Java Dynamic Web Project (Eclipse)

Tags: java, php, mysql, servlets

I am new to web development and Java servlets. So please be patient with me while I explain what I am trying to accomplish:

I am building a Time Entry application where the authenticated users can enter their time, date, project, description etc, which are then stored into a MySQL database.

The application is built using Java Servlet which dynamically generates the HTML (not JSP) interface, which the user sees and enters his/her time from. As the user enters the form with the relevant time entry information, the servlet enters these info into the MySQL database. I am using Apache Tomcat as my server.

Ideally, I would like to build a web page (or may be integrate with the same web page), where the user can see his/her previous time entries based on date or project names. The idea is simple - the user clicks on "7 days" and the MySQL returns all the time entries for last 7 days.

Since I am new to servlet programming, the only way I think I know how to do this is to write another servlet, which is invoked when the user clicks on "7 days" and the servlet reads the input, generates the MySQL query and returns the result to a new page.

I am wondering if there's a better way to do this. I haven't programmed in PHP before, but I am willing consider PHP if that's a better way to handle this. But I am not sure how to integrate PHP into my existing Dynamic Web Project inside Eclipse IDE for Java EE.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you need to accomplish in the scenario you presented can be accomplished using Java EE.  It would not be wise from a maintainability (and sanity) perspective to mix PHP in with Java EE code.

That being said, since you're using Java EE, I would say that the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern would be a good way for you to go.

It takes a little bit of time to get setup properly but will allow you to create modular, easy to maintain/understand code in the long run.

Take a look at [Servlets and JSP Pages Best Practices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html) as a starter and all the good posts on StackOverflow on developing Java web applications using MVC.